# "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:11

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure a media instance with Nginx. I've done it before, on another server, and it worked fine there. However, when I copy the same nginx vhost file over to this server (changing relative bits like the server_name), nginx gives me the following error:

```
"upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:11
```

This is my conf i try to use

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

upstream LoadBalancer {
    server 127.0.0.1:6666;
}
upstream ProxyStream {
    server 127.0.0.1:6868;
}
    
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name proxy.yourdomain.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://LoadBalancer;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_send_timeout   600;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
    
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sv1.yourdomain.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ProxyStream;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_send_timeout   600;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `nginx.conf` file is invalid. You are missing an `http { ... }` block.